# App organization and UISplitViewController

Tags: ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

I have a problem with my app organization. 
I want an home view with four buttons. Each one pushing the view to a splitView.

So in my home view, I do not want any masterView displayed, ether in portrait or landscape mode.
But in my four next views, I want the masterView displayed at any time and I want to be able to have a back button to return to the home view.

My question is how do I achieve such a thing ?

- Do I have to create my home View as the rootViewController of the app and then create one splitView per button. Then create a back button to dismiss the splitView.
- Do I have to create one single splitView and play around with the master view display. I can't figure out how to hide my master class in portrait mode on certain views and show it on other views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A UISplitViewController has to be the root view controller.

So you would start your app with a homeViewController that contains four buttons, each of which would tell your app delegate to remove the home view controller from root and create a splitViewController and make that the root.

Obviously to go back you would need a button on your splitViewController that would tell the app delegate to remove the splitViewController and replace with the newly loaded homeViewController.

---

an example of getting a viewController from a storyboard and attaching it to the window

```
window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *homeViewController = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"HomeViewController"];
[window addSubview:homeViewController.view];
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Comment: sounds a good way to do it, but I do I tell the window rootviewController to switch from a storyboard ? What kind of segue do I have to use and from where ?

Comment: If you're using storyboards I would use multiple storyboards, one for each of your four split views and a further one for your initial root.